# Functional analysis. Weak topology excercise

Tags: real-analysis

Let X be a normed linear space and let
$$S=\{f \in X^{*} : ||f||=1 \}$$

let $\{x_{n}\}$ a sequence in X. Prove that $x_{n}$ $\rightharpoonup$ $x$ if and only if $f(x_{n}) \to f(x)$ for all $f\in S$

Here i'm having problems to prove the "right to left" implication. I know that i have to prove that $x_{n}$ $\rightharpoonup$ $x$, this means that $f(x_{n}) \to f(x)$ for all $f\in X^{*}$ but from here i don't know how to continue the problem. Some ideas? how can i relate this with the hypotesis of $f(x_{n})$ converges to $f(x)$ with $f \in S$

Answer (score 1):

Pick $f\in X^*$. If $f=0$ then clearly $f(x_n)\to f(x)$. Otherwise,
$g=f/\|f\|$ is an element of $S$, hence by assumption $g(x_n)\to g(x)$.
Multiplying this by $\|f\|$ you get $f(x_n)\to f(x)$. Hence $x_n$ tends weakly to $x$.

Comment: Neither the question, nor the answer are that great, to be honest.

Comment: Great answer* i'm sorry.